# Creating a tree using the forest package such that different nodes are aligned

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I wish to create a tree using the "forest" package looking as the picture attached below (sorry, but the upload picture is not horizontally). Note that nodes in different levels should be align (such as 7,16,25 and 2,6,15,24). Since i'm only a beginner I would appreciated a simple solution. Thank !

[image: my tree]

Comment: Hi, you could be this example: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-the-forest-package-to-create-trees-in-latex/hknhtcwdkqyc#.WLg2F_nhB1s. There is too a source in .tex.

Comment: Thanks, but the nodes there are not aligned as I need.

Comment: So draw your tree with non-aligned nodes and then post the code. Somebody can then tell you how to align them. Otherwise, to answer this, I've got to copy a bunch of meaningless numbers from an image - not even upright - in another application on another virtual desktop. Life's too short.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Forest?